# Is it possible to save to and send an excel file from memory in flask?

Tags: flask

Im wanting to save an excel file temporarily to memory using openpyxl and then send the file to the user's browser.

Lets say you have the following flask app:

```
from flask import send_file
from openpyxl import Workbook

@app.route('/page', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def func():
    wb = Workbook()
    ws=wb.create_sheet()
    ws['A1'] = 'Hello World'
    filename = 'helloworld.xlsx'
    wb.save(filename)
    wb.close()
    return send_file(filename)
```

How would I save the file temporarily to memory (instead of to the flask server as the above code does) and send it to the user from memory?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
import io

from flask import Response
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
from werkzeug import FileWrapper

@app.route('/page', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def func():
    file = io.BytesIO()

    wb = Workbook(file)
    ws = wb.add_worksheet()
    ws.write('A1', 'Hello World')
    wb.close()

    file.seek(0)
    wrapped_file = FileWrapper(file)

    return Response(
        wrapped_file,
        mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        direct_passthrough=True,
    )
```

This is a little more than you asked for, but accomplishes the request. I've included some additional content from tough lessons on my end with sending files from Flask. When putting it behind a production uwsgi server (I'm using NGINX and uwsgi to serve the flask app), there is some coordinated buffering that the underlying werkzeug library does with the uswgi server. Flask's send_file would sometimes generate an NGINX 500 error with larger excel files. I've switched to using the underlying werkzeug function directly that supports Flask's send_file and it never results in any server issues.

Comment: Would this work with very large excel files? As currently I read in chunks in pandas, and then yield content, but this takes far to long and then suffers a timeout

Comment: @mp252 It does require that the entire file is read into memory at once. Therefore, memory would be your constraint in determining how large a file would be supported.